# How to pass parameters to the flyout of windows 7 gadget?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code i want to pass parameters to the flyout function but it doesnt work, i remove parameters it work . is this code true?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var now = new Date();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'http://sarafandnet.com/sites.xml',
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            $(xml).find('New').each(function() {
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                var title = $(this).find('title').text();
                var date = $(this).find('date').text();
                var url = $(this).find('url').text();
                var desc = $(this).find('desc').text();

                if (now.getDate() == date) {

                    document.getElementById("td" + date).innerHTML = '<table width="16" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td height="21" ><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="showFlyout(\'' + title + '\',\'' + desc + '\')" class="lightwindow" height="10px" title="' + title + '" caption="' + desc + '" >click</a></td></tr></table>';
                }
            });
        }
    });
});

function Init() {
    System.Gadget.Flyout.file = "flyout.html";
    // Initialize the Flyout state display.
    if (!System.Gadget.Flyout.show) {
        sFlyoutFeedback.innerText = "Flyout hidden.";
    }
}

function showFlyout(titlee, descc) {
    System.Gadget.Settings.write("title", titlee);
    System.Gadget.Settings.write("desc", descc);

    System.Gadget.Flyout.file = "flyout.html";
    System.Gadget.Flyout.show = true;

}

function showFlyout() {
    System.Gadget.Flyout.show = true;
}

function hideFlyout() {
    oGadgetDocument.getElementById("strFlyoutFeedback").innerText = "Flyout  hidden.";
    System.Gadget.Flyout.show = false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You cannot declare a function with the same name more than once; even if the functions accept different parameters.

   Your second declaration of `showFlyout` (accepting no parameters), is overriding the first.

   If you want this behaviour (optional parameters), you should do something like this:

   ```
   function showFlyout(titlee, descc) {
       if (arguments.length == 0) {
           System.Gadget.Flyout.show = true;
       } else {
           System.Gadget.Settings.write("title", titlee);
           System.Gadget.Settings.write("desc", descc);

           System.Gadget.Flyout.file = "flyout.html";
           System.Gadget.Flyout.show = true;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Each time you call `$(this)`, you're recreating **exactly** the same jQuery object... **cache it**:

   ```
   $(xml).find('New').each(function() {
       var self = $(this); // cache this

       var id = self.attr('id'); // now use self instead of this
       var title = self.find('title').text();
       var date = self.find('date').text();
       var url = self.find('url').text();
       var desc = self.find('desc').text();

       if (now.getDate() == date) {

           document.getElementById("td" + date).innerHTML = '<table width="16" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td height="21" ><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="showFlyout(\'' + title + '\',\'' + desc + '\')" class="lightwindow" height="10px" title="' + title + '" caption="' + desc + '" >click</a></td></tr></table>';
       }
   });
   ```
3. The Windows Gallery is [retired as of last week](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/looking-for-gadgets), so you will never be able to publish your Gadget to the official Gallery.

Comment: @KassemShehady: Where in the code you provided are you trying to open the Flyout with parameters? You cannot **pass parameters** when opening the Flyout, you have to open the Flyout (`System.Gadget.Flyout.show = true`), and then set a value in the global scope in (`System.Gadget.Flyout.document.parentWindow.someVar = 4`) from the Gadget, and then read it in the Flyout window (`window.someVar`)

Comment: onclick="showFlyout(\'' + title + '\',\'' + desc + '\')" here i am passing parameters to  showFlyout function which will save them in the system.gadget.settings.write. and then in the flyout i will read these variables using  system.gadget.settings.read(..)

Comment: @KassemShehady: Did you read my answer ***You cannot declare a function with the same name more than once; even if the functions accept different parameters. Your second declaration of showFlyout (accepting no parameters), is overriding the first.***. In your Flyout file, use `System.Gadget.Settings.read` (after fixing your re-declaration of `showFlyout`), and it'll work.